# Dash application icons not in alphabetical order

Tags: unity, 12.04, unity-dash, icons

The Installed icons within the Applications lens on my Unity dash are not in alphabetical order. I imagine there's a simple fix, but I don't know what to do. I've searched for a solution, but every reference to icon order I've seen has been for the launcher, not the dash.

I'm using 12.04 beta 1 and Unity 5.8.0...

[image: Dash icons not sorted alphabetically.]

Answer (score 1):

Known bug in unity-5.8 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/964325

In the future you can go here, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity

You can adjust the order displayed, often useful to order by `number`, that will list newest first, Ex. - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bugs?orderby=-id&start=0

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This is how my Installed section in Applicaiton Lens looks like - Completely sorted

[image: Properly sorted Installed section in Application Lens]

Is this a fresh install or update?

---

If you look at the application lens then you can see three sections

[image: Application lens screenshot]

1. Recently Used
2. Installed Apps
3. Available for Download

The apps in `Recently Used` are not supposed to be in Alphabetical order. It has to be sorted as "most recently used" to "least recently used"

Then the next section you have is `Installed` apps. As you can see from the list, it is alphabetically sorted.

Then the third section is `Apps Available for Download` which is well a random selection from the repositories

---

In Home Lens

[image: Home Lens recently Used]

As you can see from Home Lens only `Recent Apps` are shown which as per the name are not supposed to be sorted alphabetically

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I guess my question wasn't specific enough. My Installed icons are the ones that are out of order.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot, with the issues marked on the snapshot?

Comment: I have no image editor on this machine, but the problem should be self-evident in the screenshot. Thanks for you help.

Comment: This was a fresh install of 12.04 beta 1 from a week or so ago, updated last night with Update Manager.